# Facebook feed dialog picture size

Tags: facebook

On a website we have a Facebook share button. With Facebook's javascript version of it's Feed dialog, a user can upload an image to his timeline. As Facebook indicates, we are using an image size of 1200px by 630px. It all works, only the picture is rendered small. What do we need to do for Facebook to render a larger size?